# Can't make my Javascript code work to disable an input box on a loading page

Tags: javascript, html

I have in an html file a form with a dropdown that disables an input box when a certain value is selected. It works well, but then, when the user clicks on the form's submit button, it refreshes the page after having done some calculations and enables the input box. I want it to remain disabled. I managed to have the value of the dropdown being stored, but can't do the same for my input box. My knowledge of JS is next to zero but I came up with the following script, which I assumed should have done the job when the page is reloaded, yet it doesn't. Could you please tell me what is wrong with the code below? Thanks!

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var ComboboxType = document.getElementById('Type').value;
      var InputToDisable = document.getElementById("MyInput");

      if (ComboboxType.value == 'Some Value') {
          InputToDisable.disabled = true;
      }
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: do you need to refresh the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without jQuery even, see the example below.

Basically, you get the input element using `document.getElementById`. Then, just to be safe, I check if it exist. Than, just disable it.

```js
window.onload = function(e) {
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  if(input) {
    input.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="foo" id="input" placeholder="disabled" />
```

Comment: Just needed to make a small amendment to adapt it to my needs, but this worked great otherwise. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create an ajax request in jQuery ( from what I see you use this library in your code ) to handle the refresh problem.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Example:

```
    $("#my_form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
        var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

        $.ajax({
           url : post_url,
           type: request_method,
           data : form_data,
           success: (response) => {   
               if(response){
                  //do something
               }
           }
        });
    });
```